# Website builds but publish to Azure fails after deleting files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, publishing

Using Visual Studio 2019 to build a .Net Core website and publish to Azure was working fine up until I just deleted a DataContext file and an Entity class through Visual Studio. I can build and bring the site up locally without any issue but when I try to publish the site to Azure I get an error that the two files I deleted could not be found. I've checked in my code along with the solution file. The message is correct, those files are no longer available but I'm not understanding why it's looking for them since I deleted them through VS and the solution/project file should have been updated. I've done some searching but can't find anything that specifically address this. I guess I could roll back to right before I deleted the files but then I'l have to update some code. Anyone know if I can look somewhere that is referencing these files for publishing so I can delete the reference? I've searched the whole solution for the name of the files hoping I could find a reference but it isn't finding anything.

Comment: You can wait for more detailed answer (for instance checking if not messed with debug/release/publish profiles), but my advice is to manually delete /bin and /obj from your projects' directories and rebuild the solution again. No matter what you are doing in Visual Studio, it solves 99% of weird problems.

Comment: @MichałJarzyna yep, that was it. I should have known to do that as I've seen it posted many times before...just didn't think about it at the time. Thanks.